# Drupal 7 database insert is not working for some users

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drupal, drupal-7

In drupal 7, I wrote a simple custom registration form module. HTML Form has 4 fields Fname, Lname, email id and contact number. I have created registration content type. I have used common hooks e.g. form, menu, form submi hook and for database I am using default database insert's of Drupal 7. I am using code which is in Drupal 7's online documentation.

Here is the problem, For some users registration form submission is working without any errors but for other users, they are not able to save a registration entry to database. Some times after submit button blank page appears or sometimes it dont insert value to database but shows "inserted successfully" message.

I don't know why its working for some user and not for other users.
Is there any suggestion/solutions from you ...? Anything I am missing to check in drupal?

Comment: Check your error logs/watchdog. It may be that MySQL or PHP is locking up/running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below condition:

1. In hook menu check access callback is set to true.
2. check access log of database.

If above solution is not working please share your code.